# How to find JavaScript functions in a JavaScript (.js) file?

Tags: javascript

I need to find or list out all the JavaScript methods in a `.js` file.

Comment: Did you look in the file? What seems to be the problem?

Comment: List out how? Do you want to write a program to list them out in, say, UI of some application, or do you want to see the list of functions so that you can "see" them and use them for your programming?

Comment: same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493833/list-of-global-user-defined-functions-in-javascript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [List of global user defined functions in javascript ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493833/list-of-global-user-defined-functions-in-javascript)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418388/how-can-get-a-list-of-the-functions-in-a-javascript-file

Answer (score 4):

You can programmatically get a list of all the user-defined global functions as follows:

```
var listOfFunctions = [];

for (var x in window) {

  if (window.hasOwnProperty(x) && 
      typeof window[x] === 'function' &&
      window[x].toString().indexOf('[native code]') > 0) {

    listOfFunctions.push(x);
  }
}
```

The `listOfFunctions` array will contain the names of all the global functions which are not native.

---

**UPDATE:** As [@CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5445/cms) pointed out in the comments below, the above won't work in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier for global [function declarations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#Function_constructor_vs._function_declaration_vs._function_expression).

Comment: You'll get a [surprise](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2005/05/04/414684.aspx) when you try this on IE<=8. IE can't enumerate identifiers from Function Declarations in the global scope :(

Comment: you're welcome. That's IMO one of the worst bugs on IE. Fortunately it's already fixed on IE9. :)

Comment: @CMS: Yes I agree that it's an awful bug, but does it have practical importance? ... ie. Is iteration over global function declarations useful in browser scripting (in general)?

Answer (score 0):

In [Notepad++](http://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad-plus/) there is a plugin named [Function List](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/Function%20List/) - you might find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to write a parser in order to understand all the grammar. You might be able to use an existing parser.