# Generate a list of existing function across multiple files in js using any script

Tags: javascript, bash, shell, automation

I have a lot of javascript files in a particular path. Every file has a lot of functions. As per my requirement, I've to document all function names in an excel sheet. So is there any way to automate these using any scripts or tools?

Expected output
Format->  Filename - Function name

```
Sample -> samplejs.js - Test
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find JavaScript functions in a JavaScript (.js) file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853274/how-to-find-javascript-functions-in-a-javascript-js-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is -[Show Functions VS Code Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qrti.funclist)

Modified setting.json of this extension to get the JS files functions.

```
{
            "extensions": [
                ".ts",
                ".php",
                ".js"
            ],
            "native": "/(?:^|\\s)function\\s+\\w+\\(/mg",
            "display": "/\\s*function\\s+(\\w+)/1",
            "sort": 0
        },
```