# Return all of the functions that are defined in a Javascript file

Tags: javascript, reflection

For the following script, how can I write a function that returns all of the script's functions as an array? I'd like to return an array of the functions defined in the script so that I can print a summary of every function that is defined in the script.

```
    function getAllFunctions(){ //this is the function I'm trying to write
        //return all the functions that are defined in the script where this
        //function is defined.
        //In this case, it would return this array of functions [foo, bar, baz,
        //getAllFunctions], since these are the functions that are defined in this
        //script.
    }

    function foo(){
        //method body goes here
    }

    function bar(){
        //method body goes here
    }

    function baz(){
        //method body goes here
    }
```

Comment: To clarify, getAllFunctions() should only return the functions that are defined in the script itself, and nothing else.

Comment: I clarified the original question so that the question is no longer ambiguous.

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493833/list-of-global-user-defined-functions-in-javascript

Comment: [Already been asked.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493833/list-of-global-user-defined-functions-in-javascript?lq=1)

Comment: I'm not sure if that's an exact duplicate, since the asker of that question only wanted to filter out "native functions" as opposed to "user-defined functions." That question is close to what I'm looking for, but the question is not an exact match for my question.

Comment: Fortunately, there's dozens, maybe hundreds?, of other "Javascript Reflection" queries. Look at the long **Related** list to the right. They can't all be rejected as insufficient.

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of this function, are you unable to define the functions on their own object - which would make detection of them far easier. I'm failing to understand the purpose behind the "getAllFunctions" function.

Comment: I edited the question slightly to explain the use case.

Comment: Also, this question appears to be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418388/how-can-get-a-list-of-the-functions-in-a-javascript-file

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Declare it in a pseudo namespace, for example like this:

```
   var MyNamespace = function(){
    function getAllFunctions(){ 
      var myfunctions = [];
      for (var l in this){
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(l) && 
            this[l] instanceof Function &&
            !/myfunctions/i.test(l)){
          myfunctions.push(this[l]);
        }
      }
      return myfunctions;
     }

     function foo(){
        //method body goes here
     }

     function bar(){
         //method body goes here
     }

     function baz(){
         //method body goes here
     }
     return { getAllFunctions: getAllFunctions
             ,foo: foo
             ,bar: bar
             ,baz: baz }; 
    }();
    //usage
    var allfns = MyNamespace.getAllFunctions();
    //=> allfns is now an array of functions. 
    //   You can run allfns[0]() for example
```

Comment: +1 for rightly capturing functions, I believe I had seen similar way in John Resig's **Secrets of JavaScript Ninja** book

Comment: It works, but this seems a bit redundant:
     return { getAllFunctions: getAllFunctions
             ,foo: foo
             ,bar: bar
             ,baz: baz };
Is it possible to do this without hard-coding the name of each function?

Comment: @Anderson: you need a reference to the functions themselves, but it doesn't have to be public. Alternatively you can assign an object like `var fns = {foo:foo,bar:bar ...}` variable within `MyNamespae` and query that using `getAllFunctions`. Than you only have to expose `getAllFunctions` -> `return {getAllfunctions:getAllfunctions};`

Comment: If I use the Angular.js annotate function here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/dde1b2949727c297e214c99960141bfad438d7a4/src/auto/injector.js#L63-L96 `annotate(allfns[0])` I get a `[]` of parameters, while it works calling the actual function `annotate(MyNamespace. foo)`. Why?

Answer (score 18):

Here is a function that will return all functions defined in the document, what it does is it iterates through all objects/elements/functions and displays only those whose type is "function".

```
function getAllFunctions(){ 
        var allfunctions=[];
          for ( var i in window) {
        if((typeof window[i]).toString()=="function"){
            allfunctions.push(window[i].name);
          }
       }
    }
```

​
Here is a [jsFiddle working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DSmqy/8/).

​Add the function at the last and this snippet `getAllFunctions().slice(48, -4)` will just return the user defined functions in Vivaldi.

Comment: The problem with this is that it will catch all functions defined in previous scripts that were attached to window. And it's a very bad idea to toss things onto window in the first place.

Comment: Adding `&&window[i].toString().indexOf("native")==-1` to the if fixes that.

Comment: Should this still work in today's browsers? I paste it into DevTools Console and it returns 'undefined'

Comment: @golimar It returns `undefined` because it doesn't have a `return` statement. I tested it again [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4gfz158x/), and it still generates a list of function names.

Answer (score 3):

More than 1 hour wasted on this.

This is read `.js` file from `node.js`

1.Install a node module:

```
npm i esprima
```

2.Assume you have a function `func1` declared like below, in a file `a.js` in current directory:

```
var func1 = function (str1, str2) {
    //
};
```

3.And you would like to get name of it, that is `func1`, the code is below:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const esprima = require("esprima");

let file = fs.readFileSync("./a.js", "utf8");

let tree = esprima.parseScript(file);
tree.body.forEach((el) => {
    if (el.type == "VariableDeclaration") {
        // console.log(el);
        console.log(el.declarations);
        console.log(el.declarations[0].id);
        console.log(el.declarations[0].id.name);
    }
});
```

4.You can also get other details like parameters `str1`, `str2`, etc, uncomment the `console.log(el)` line to see other details.

5.You can put both above code parts in one file, to get the details of current file (`a.js`).

Answer (score 1):

```js
function foo(){/*SAMPLE*/}
function bar(){/*SAMPLE*/}
function www_WHAK_com(){/*SAMPLE*/}

for(var i in this) {
 if((typeof this[i]).toString()=="function"&&this[i].toString().indexOf("native")==-1){
  document.write('<li>'+this[i].name+"</li>")
 }
}
```