# Get a list of currently defined functions in node.js

Tags: node.js

Is there any function that can be used to list all of the currently defined functions in node.js? I'd like to create a function like this:

```
function getAllDefinedFunctions(){
    //return all the functions that are currently defined
}
```

Comment: I realized that I made a duplicate of my own question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279441/return-all-of-the-functions-that-are-defined-in-a-javascript-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `for / in` loop to loop over all properties in `this` (the global object) and check whether `typeof this[name]` is `'function'`.