# Count the javascript functions on a page (with javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function

Good day all.
I would like to count the js functions present on a given page, and then send this number via ajax (the ajax part is the simple part) do you think is it possible to achieve that in javascript? what should be the best way to do it?
thanks in advance.

explanation:
I'm trying to figure out how to counter measure some fraud attempts on some subscription pages, I suspect that some javascript is injected on the page before the user click, so having the number of functions present at the load event, and then the number of those present on the submit event, should lead me in the right direction.

Comment: Do you understand that you can do fraud even without adding new functions, and whatever code you write, it doesn't execute again after it is loaded onto the browser?

Comment: sure, this is only one of the researches I'm doing to this front.
what I would like to do is a function that counts functions, so I can fire it whenever I need.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to make a checksum over the whole DOM

Comment: @freedomn-m You know what I am trying to say, but still you ask!

Comment: @brandelizer I don't think that would either be possible, coz due to the dynamic nature, new code may be injected, or removed, say for eg., animations, user activity?

Comment: I'm thinking about counting all the word "function" into the page... but this will not count the external files.

Comment: Possible solutions here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279441/return-all-of-the-functions-that-are-defined-in-a-javascript-file

Comment: You executing js doesn't have access to the source file it's executing from

Answer (score 2):

Well, if someone is injecting code to your site, they could just as easily use that code to turn off your code counting functions. You can never trust anything that happens on the client side and must validate everything on the server.

As for the technical side, you'd use a tool like [acorn](https://github.com/ternjs/acorn) to traverse the syntax tree and find all `FunctionDeclaration` and `FunctionExpressions` (and arrows, concise method definitions and methods). That would not find *all* functions, but it would find all statically created ones.

Once the code started executing it's impossible since it's easily reducable to the halting problem. You don't know if a code will create a function at some point in the future.

Comment: yes, indeed they "could" turn off my CM, but I'me actually researching this, so I'm only interested in view some numbers, in this case, the number of functions at the page load, and the number of functions at the submit of the form.

Comment: Then no, there is no "global counter of created functions", you can _try_ overriding `Function` itself with a subclass but I don't think that'd work in most environments.

Comment: understand.. the overriding options doesn't seems the way atm.