# How to display methods name from a JavaScript file

Tags: javascript

I have been searching for an option to display a list of methods in a JavaScript file. Are there any methods to pass a JavaScript file name in a `for` loop, and then to display the function names from the JavaScript file?

I am having list of javascript files, in each of js files, there are various functions. I want to display list of method names in browser window.

For example,if there are 2 functions in arithmetic.js file.

```
function add(){
}
function subtract(){
}
```

Then, in an html file, i want to display those two method names such as add, subtract..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return all of the functions that are defined in a Javascript file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279441/return-all-of-the-functions-that-are-defined-in-a-javascript-file)

Answer (score 0):

Answer to this has already been given by @Kooilnc, to see it follow below link

[Reflection in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279441/return-all-of-the-functions-that-are-defined-in-a-javascript-file)

It displays all functions names of browser page
pls check the below link
http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=F0VB7DGKT3DX

Comment: I have checked this, but it returns the browser windows methods and the methods inside the script tag of html file. I am having js file seperately. I want to display list of methods from that particular js file.

Answer (score 0):

i dont think there is a simple way to this , if this is your files write a function inside every file that return the name of the function